# Laravel 5.2 Service provider not booting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I have a weird issue with a service provider. I have a ComposerServiceProvider with a `dd("I'm loaded");` in the `boot()` function. Nothing is happening.

I also have `App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class` in config/app.php. I ran `composer dump-autoload` several times. Can anybody help?

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        dd("I'm loaded");
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

EDIT: Here's my bootstrap/cache/services.php, where it also does not appear, even after php artisan clear-compiled

```
<?php return array (
  'providers' =>
  array (
    0 => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider',
    1 => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider',
    2 => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider',
    3 => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    4 => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    5 => 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider',
    6 => 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    7 => 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    8 => 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    9 => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FoundationServiceProvider',
    10 => 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider',
    11 => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider',
    12 => 'Illuminate\\Pagination\\PaginationServiceProvider',
    13 => 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider',
    14 => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    15 => 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider',
    16 => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    17 => 'Illuminate\\Session\\SessionServiceProvider',
    18 => 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider',
    19 => 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider',
    20 => 'Illuminate\\View\\ViewServiceProvider',
    21 => 'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider',
    22 => 'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider',
    23 => 'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider',
    24 => 'App\\Providers\\HelperServiceProvider',
    25 => 'App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider',
    26 => 'C4studio\\EmailCssInliner\\EmailCssInlinerServiceProvider',
    27 => 'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider',
    28 => 'Radic\\BladeExtensions\\BladeExtensionsServiceProvider',
  ),
  'eager' =>
  array (
    0 => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider',
    1 => 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider',
    2 => 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    3 => 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    4 => 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    5 => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FoundationServiceProvider',
    6 => 'Illuminate\\Pagination\\PaginationServiceProvider',
    7 => 'Illuminate\\Session\\SessionServiceProvider',
    8 => 'Illuminate\\View\\ViewServiceProvider',
    9 => 'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider',
    10 => 'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider',
    11 => 'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider',
    12 => 'App\\Providers\\HelperServiceProvider',
    13 => 'App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider',
    14 => 'C4studio\\EmailCssInliner\\EmailCssInlinerServiceProvider',
    15 => 'Radic\\BladeExtensions\\BladeExtensionsServiceProvider',
  ),
  'deferred' =>
  array (
    'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\Broadcasting\\Factory' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\Broadcasting\\Broadcaster' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\Bus\\Dispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\Bus\\QueueingDispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider',
    'cache' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    'cache.store' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    'memcached.connector' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    'command.cache.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider',
    'command.clear-compiled' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.auth.resets.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.config.cache' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.config.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.down' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.environment' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.key.generate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.optimize' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.route.cache' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.route.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.route.list' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.tinker' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.up' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.view.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.app.name' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.auth.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.cache.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.console.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.controller.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.event.generate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.event.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.job.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.listener.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.middleware.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.model.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.policy.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.provider.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.failed-table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.request.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.seeder.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.session.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.serve' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.test.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.vendor.publish' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'migrator' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'migration.repository' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.rollback' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.reset' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.refresh' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.install' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.status' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'migration.creator' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.migrate.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'seeder' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.seed' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'composer' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.failed' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.retry' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.forget' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.flush' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'hash' => 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider',
    'mailer' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider',
    'swift.mailer' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider',
    'swift.transport' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\\Contracts\\Pipeline\\Hub' => 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'queue' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'queue.worker' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'queue.listener' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'queue.failer' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.work' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.listen' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'command.queue.restart' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'queue.connection' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider',
    'redis' => 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider',
    'auth.password' => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'auth.password.broker' => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'translator' => 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'translation.loader' => 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'validator' => 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'validation.presence' => 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'html' => 'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'form' => 'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Collective\\Html\\HtmlBuilder' => 'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Collective\\Html\\FormBuilder' => 'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider',
  ),
  'when' =>
  array (
    'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
    'Collective\\Html\\HtmlServiceProvider' =>
    array (
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can You attach `bootstrap/cache/service.php` content?

Comment: Is this everything you have in ComposerServiceProvider?

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys It definitely doesn't appear in bootstrap/cache/service.php. 

I tried php artisan clear-compiled, it still doesn't help

Comment: I can't create any ServiceProviders anymore. I do php artisan make:provider AbcServiceProvider, add AbcService provider in config/app.php, and it's just not called.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Got an answer on another forum from rodrigo.pedra:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

The first will clear any cached config files, and the later will clear the services cache

Comment: This worked for me as well on a production machine after I spent hours trying to figure it out. Happy day!

Answer (score 4):

You said you tried php `artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload` but have you tried running all those commands?

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @IllesPeter Have you tried deleting `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file?

Comment: Well, php artisan clear-compiled does that, but manually deleting it won't work either

Answer (score 2):

I had a weird issue as well: with deferred providers, until I saw this

> To defer the loading of a provider, set the defer property to true and define a provides method. The provides method returns the service container bindings that the provider registers:

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#deferred-providers)

Answer (score 1):

In case your ServiceProvider class implements the `boot()` method, make sure you're invoking the `parent::boot()` method as well.

At least in my case (Laravel 5.3.6) the missing `parent::boot()` has prevented the service provider from booting properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
```

Above's command worked but, in my case, I had to delete all files under **storage/views/** to use the directive blade from my provider.